# format any mail into readable text

Tags: python, html, python-2.x, email

Scope is to throw any mail, html or plain or multipart into this and receive a readable formatted text that deals with special characters and html issues. Field of usage: System that imports mails into a mysql db, or prints them to pdf etc.

What can I improve here?

```
import imapclient, pyzmail, html2text

"""
Connect to IMAP. Login and select folder.
retreive UID of Mails and fetch the latest.
return the body of the latest message
"""

def latestMail():
    imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.server.com', ssl=False)
    imapObj.login('username', 'password')
    imapObj.select_folder('INFO', readonly=True)
    UIDs = imapObj.search(criteria='ALL', charset=None)
    rawMessages = imapObj.fetch(UIDs[0], ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[UIDs[0]]['BODY[]'])
    return message

"""
Open message object, check if content is html or plain or both.
If both, only plain will be taken. for Plain, decodes the
message if charset is given, if not we will use system default
for html, additionally format html so the information
is exportable to any db.
"""

def parser(message):
    if message.text_part is not None and message.html_part is not None:
        multipart = True
    else:
        multipart = False

    if message.text_part is not None:
        try:
            body = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
        except TypeError:
            body = message.text_part.get_payload()

    if message.html_part is not None and multipart is False:
        try:
            body = html2text.html2text(message.html_part.get_payload().decode(message.html_part.charset))
        except Exception:
            raise Systemexit
    return body


print parser(latestMail())
```